Sending a message to telegram's Secret Chat with Gram,js
I'm trying to send a message to a telegram's secret chat using Gram.js and i'm getting a successful response but the messages are never showing up.
Here is the response i'm getting when i try to send the message :
    {
        CONSTRUCTOR_ID: 1443858741,
        SUBCLASS_OF_ID: 3382591056,
        className: 'messages.SentEncryptedMessage',
        classType: 'constructor',
        date: 1725350460
      }

As you can see i'm getting a messages.SentEncryptedMessage but the messages are never showing up in the secret chat.
Code i'm using :

Here is the code im using to create the secret chat :

async function getDhConfig(
    client: TelegramClient
): Promise<Api.messages.DhConfig | null> {
    try {
        const res = await client.invoke(
            new Api.messages.GetDhConfig({
                version: 0,
                randomLength: 256,
            })
        );
        return res as Api.messages.DhConfig;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to get dh config:", error);
        return null;
    }
}

async function openSecretChat(client: TelegramClient, user: IUser) {
    const dh = await getDhConfig(client);
    if (!dh) return;
    const g: number = dh.g;
    const p: Buffer = dh.p;
    const a: Buffer = dh.random;

    const aBigInt = bigInt.fromArray([...a], 256);
    const pBigInt = bigInt.fromArray([...p], 256);

    const gA = bigInt(g).modPow(aBigInt, pBigInt);
    const gABuffer = Buffer.from(gA.toArray(256).value);
    const verifiedUsersLength = (await getUsersWithSecretChat()).length;
    try {
        console.log("Sending secret chat request...");
        const res = await client.invoke(
            new Api.messages.RequestEncryption({
                userId: new Api.InputUser({
                    userId: bigInt(user.chatId),
                    accessHash: bigInt(user.chatId),
                }),
                randomId: verifiedUsersLength + 1,
                gA: gABuffer,
            })
        );
        console.log(res);
        console.log("Secret chat request sent");
        return res as Api.EncryptedChat;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to send secret chat request:", error);
        return null;
    }
}


After creating a secret chat i save the secret chat id and accessHash to the user object, Then when the Encryption is accepted i try to send a message to that chat.

Code for sending the message :
async function sendMessageInSecretChat(
    client: TelegramClient,
    user: IUser,
    message: string
) {
    if (!user.secretChatId) {
        return;
    }
    const msg = {
        message,
    };
    const messageBuffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(msg));

    try {
        const result = await client.invoke(
            new Api.messages.SendEncrypted({
                peer: new Api.InputEncryptedChat({
                    chatId: user.secretChatId,
                    accessHash: bigInt(user.accessHash),
                }),
                randomId: bigInt(Date.now()),
                data: messageBuffer,
            })
        );
        console.log("Encrypted message sent:", result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Failed to send encrypted message:", error);
    }
}


After sending calling this function i get the following response :

    {
        CONSTRUCTOR_ID: 1443858741,
        SUBCLASS_OF_ID: 3382591056,
        className: 'messages.SentEncryptedMessage',
        classType: 'constructor',
        date: 1725350460
      }


But the messages are never showing up in the secret chat.

I have also tried to manually aes encrypt the message object but i get the same behavior (same response but messages never show up).


Any ideas why this is happening and how i can fix it ?
Thank you very much.
